# More or Less Condition always valid

Tags: java, if-statement

I have a method with 2 double parameters: 
 1. a value that I want to check
 2. the value I want to check it with, it's either 0.99 or 1.0 but not fixed values,
the return value is 2.

The expected result is if 1 is less or equal to 0.99 then it's Good, but if 1 is more or equal to 1.0 it's Bad

```
static Double check (Double var1, Double var2) {
    Double obj= 0.0;

    if (var1 >= var2)
        obj = var2;
    else if (var1 <= var2)
        obj = var2;
    return obj; }
```

var1 enters the same for the two times but var2 is the one changed,
The problem is if the value is less than 0.99 (for example 0.5) it's always less than 1.0, and if it's more than 1.0 it's always more than 0.99, it gives me two results

Comment: In your code you are always assigning `var2` to `obj` regardless or the `if` or `else`

Comment: So first check if the value is :> 1. Btw. what should happen with values between 0.99 and 1?

Comment: Why not use the primitive type `Double`? Why do you need to specify the else? There's no way to reach that.

Comment: @Henry I take the closest 2 digit numbers after a decimal dot before entering the method

Comment: Wh- why are you trying to `return false` in a `Object` (returning) method? `Double` is techinically incorrect. Case sensitive. Either way, in both the `if` and the `else` statements, you return the same values.

Comment: condition in if or elseif or else statement must not have Intersection

Answer (score 0):

When you say for sure that,  var2 is either 0.99 or 1.0, then you can simply check like this right:

```
static boolean check (Double var1) {

    return !(var1 >= 1.0);
}
```

Comment: No, it's not a fixed value

Comment: But as per your expected result explanation, ("The expected result is if 1 is less or equal to 0.99 then it's Good, but if 1 is more or equal to 1.0 it's Bad"), this is a possible solution. May be you need to explain the expected result a little more detailed way, so that we can help.

Comment: Don't split boolean returns like this. `return !(var1 >= 1.0)`.

Answer (score -1):

The code can help you:

```
static Object check (Double var1, Double var2) {
   Object obj=new Object();

   if (var1 >= var2) {
      obj = var1;
      return obj; 
   }
   else {
      obj = var2;
      return obj; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Under what circumstances are you expecting `return false;` to run?

Answer (score -1):

Wh- why are you trying to `return false` in a `Object` (returning) method? Case sensitive. Either way, in both the `if` and the `else` statements, you return the same values.

```
static double check (Double var1, Double var2) { // You are returning doubles. Not objects.
   double obj;

   if (var1 >= var2) {
      obj = var1; // not var2, otherwise the else-if statement would be the exact same
      return obj; 
   }
   else if (var1 < var2) {
      obj = var2;
      return obj; 
   }
   else
      return false; // Throws error, I don't know what you want to do with this.
}
```

Don't forget that java is case-sensitive.

Comment: It was changed, it's fixed now.

Comment: I need the var2 that passed for validation in another method (previous method), so if the 0.99 passed I'd know it's good but It always passes the 0.99 and 1.0

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand. Dali Rejeesh's suggestion seems correct. Unless you can prove his wrong (not what you asked for), then mark it as right. Same goes with everyone's. You don't have to tell us, but think about it.